# Assigning url to an ajax (js) function into Java EE project

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I'm experimenting with my first project in Ajax and I'm having a problem with assigning an absolute URL that points to the file to fetch from the server.

This is my function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function fetchData(url, objectID){

      var pageRequest=null;
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest)pageRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();

      else if(window.ActiveXObject)pageRequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      else return false;

      pageRequest.onreadystatechange= function(){
          var object=document.getElementById(objectID);
          object.innerHTML = pageRequest.responseText;
       }

      pageRequest.open("GET",url,true);
      pageRequest.send(null);

   }
</script>
```

and it's called like this:

```
  <div id="control" onclick="fetchData('/WEB-INF/views/data.jsp','message');">Click here for Ajax!</div>
```

Tomcat returns a `404 no file source found` error. 
The file to fetch is at the same level as the other JSP files, this is the structure in Eclipse:

```
Project>
  WebContent>
    WEB-INF>
      home.jsp
      index.jsp
      **data.jsp**
      otherjsp
```

Shall I put that file somewhere else?

I have been trying to change the URL, but nothing.
The rest of the application works fine, so the requests are flowing properly.

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with your project layout, Ajax or any HTTP Call will not find the path

/WEB-INF/views/data.jsp

Because WEB-INF is protected from your JSP Container, try to put your JSP Files outside the WEB-INF directory.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-web-apps/web-app-directory-layout.html

Comment: Ah! this rings a bell! will try it and let you know asap

Answer (score 0):

i hope the issue is with the url  , can u give the absolute path instead of '/WEB-INF/views/data.jsp' and try again

Answer (score 0):

change the url as like  views/data.jsp
otherwise try below 
keep all the jsp files inside webcontent and use this url views/data.jsp